# is there a way to delete several items at once in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime

I'm working with Python 3.11. I have a dictionary whose keys are datetime objects and whose values are strings.

```python
dates = {datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1): "a", 
         datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 4): "b",
         datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 25): "c",
         datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 17): "d",
         datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 15): "e",
         datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 17): "f",
         datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 3): "g"}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to remove all the elements that have already passed (other than iterating through all the elements). For example in this case `datetime.datetime.now() = datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 9)` so the result dictionary will be:

```python
dates = {datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 17): "f",
         datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 3): "g"}
```

This code works in case the dictionary is ordered by date (which may not be the case):

```python
new_dates = {}
now = datetime.datetime.now()
for k, v in reversed(dates.items()):
    if k < now:
        break
    new_dates[k] = v
```

But I would like to know if there is any other way without a loop or thay might work in a disorderly dictionary.

Comment: No, there isn't any shortcut to finding all the dictionary elements that meet some condition.

Comment: Maybe instead of a dictionary you could use a binary tree. Then you can delete an entire subtree.

Comment: `new_dates={k:v for k,v in dates.items() if k>now}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could form a new Dictionary using a comprehension; order does not matter:

```
dates2 = {k:v for k, v in dates.items() if k > now}
```

which gives

```
{datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 17, 0, 0): 'f', datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 3, 0, 0): 'g'}
```

Comment: This still iterates through all of the items which OP apparently doesn't want. But I think its the right way to do it.

Comment: @tdelaney I was just wondering if there is another way of filtering a dictionary (similiar to how you can filter a pandas DataFrame) but apparently there isn't so I just going to use list comprehension. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @PabloGonzalez - filter still needs to iterate under the covers. Its just hidden from view. It has the advantage that the iteration may be in C on  primitive data types. But if its a python string column, that advantage is mostly done away with. There is also the python `filter`, but it would be pretty ugle. maybe `d = dict(filter(lambda kv:kv[0]>now, dates.items()))`.

Comment: @PabloGonzalez - and now that I think about it, since comprehensions are the normal way that python filters things, it would be redundant to also add that sort of functionality to each of the collections in the standard libs.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `SortedDict` in the sortedcontainers package.  It behaves just like a dictionary, but has additional methods.
You will have to install it via pip.

```
# Binary search to find the index of the first element larger than now
index = dates.bisect_right(now)
# Delete everything now or below
del dates.keys()[:index]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the keys and sort them, then loop over that.

```
for date in sorted(dates):
    if date >= now:
        break
    del dates[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python one-liner does this magic for us. One-liners more are useful especially when we need to create a new `list` or new `dict` iterating over the existing `list` or `dict`

```
import datetime
dates = {datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1): "a", 
         datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 4): "b",
         datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 25): "c",
         datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 17): "d",
         datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 15): "e",
         datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 17): "f",
         datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 3): "g"} 

now = datetime.datetime.now()

dict = {k : v for k, v in dates.items() if k >= now}

print(dict)
```